# Ajax call in different web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I've 2 web applications. I want to make an ajax call from one web application(say Application1) to another web application(say Application2).

I'm doing it like this

```
  var ajax_url = "http://localhost:50224/common/IsUserOnline";
    $.ajax({
        url: ajax_url,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: { customerId: '@Model.UserId' },
        success: function (response) {
            var data = response.Data;
            if (data.isUserOnline == false) {
                $("#IsUserActive").val('false');
            }
            else {
                $("#IsUserActive").val('true');
            }
        }
    });
    if ($("#IsUserActive").val() == "false") {
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("SessionExpired", "Home")';
    }
```

However i get the following error. `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` Is there a way i can make a hit to Application2 and get the data?

Comment: [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: try googling that errror .... will find thousands of results. If you control the other domain you need to enable CORS

Comment: i tried `jsonp` that made the hit but now it giver error `Unexpected token `

Comment: @charlietfl : how can i enable CORS?

Comment: won't get jsonp unless script is set to return jsonp

Comment: That question can be answered in google